# Ajax dont activate php code

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to remove product from session cart.I'm sending request from Ajax to event on click and nothing happens.Here is my code.I don't get any response,like the button at all don't work anything. I on button press to erase id from session data and remove product div.

```
function removeFromBasket(item) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                alert('item removed')
            }
            else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                alert("request error 400");
            }
            else{
                alert("something went wrong");
            }
        };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","cart.php?remove="+item,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

cart.php

```
    <?php
    require "cfg.php";
    if(isset($_GET['remove'])){
        $id = $_GET['remove'];
    $items = $_SESSION["cart"];
    if(($key = array_search($id, $items)) !== false) {
        unset($items[$key]);
        $ses = $_SESSION["cart"] = array_values($items);
    }
    print_r($ses);
    die();


    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <?php

    $cart = Session::get("cart");
    $cartItems = array_keys($cart);
    $q = "select * from items where id in (".implode(",",$cartItems).")";
    $db = Database::getInstance();
    $res = $db->_db->query($q);
    foreach($res as $item){
      ?>
      <form method="post" action="" class='.remove'>
      <div style='border:1px solid blue;padding:4px;'>
        <?=$item['name']?> (<?=$cart[$item['id']]?>)
    <input class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' onclick='removeFromBasket(<?= $cart[$item['id']] ?>)' name='submit' type='button' value='Remove' >
      </div>

      <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server? Why are you including the jQuery library if you're not going to use it?

Comment: i get this message  Uncaught ReferenceError: removeFromBasket is not defined onclick @ cart.php:18

Comment: Is the JavaScript in a separate file than the HTML?

Comment: yes it is.I do the same with add to basket and it works.And its also in deferent file.

Comment: Are you including the JS file in the PHP file?

Comment: it seems to be that is the problem.I put in the same file,and now i get responses on alert from my function that something is wrong when i click on button,but 3 times,and after that alert that item is removed,but isnt.Ajax  is sending request,its not showing error 400,but seems like php code isnt good.

Comment: i have autoloader.